# How to use one DatePickerDialog for multiple EditText

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have an activity with 2 EditText (startDate and endDate).

I have created a function that i pass it an EditText and it will show a DatePicker:

```
private void showDatePicker(EditText et) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    if (!Global.isEmpty(et)) {

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Global.USER_FRIENDLY_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
            calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(et.getText().toString()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error setting the date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    picker.show();
}
```

When i pick a date, i will get a callback to the onDateSet() function with the date choosen.

My questions is, how can i tell for which EditText it is?

I know there is a "DatePicker view" that is passed as an argument to the onDateSet(), but cannot seem to figure out how to use it or even if i should.

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431250/how-to-achieve-multiple-datepicker-functionality-with-two-buttons-and-save-those/30433506#30433506).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a Tag to DatePicker object of your `DatepickerDialog` by calling `picker.getDatePicker()` and `setTag()` .The same tag can be retrieved from the datePicker object in  your call back function `onDateSet()`

like

```
DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listner , calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
 DatePicker pick = picker.getDatePicker().setTag(et.getId());
```

and

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
  Log.d("", " " + datePicker.getTag());
// based on the returned tag you can decide what to do...

}
```

Comment: No, this if statement should be in the onDateSet(), which is a listener callback and i have no reference there to the EditText. Unless of course i set the "chosen" EditText as a global variable. But, i want to know if it's possible to achieve this using the passed DatePicker from the onDateSet().

Comment: Try setting a tag in DatePicker object while creating the dialog and get it on callback to compare it.

Comment: i thought of this also, but there is not setTag method on the picker object :)

Comment: Use picker.getDatePicker().setTag(et.getId()) and getTag in OnDateSet method(). this will work .. you can use something else to set as tag if you don;t like to compare id...  I will edit the answer.

Comment: It worked! this solution is the best instead of using a global variable to save the edittext that is selected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as this code is working in my app

```
public void showDialog(EditText ed){
    final EditText e = ed;
    e.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day

            dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    e.setText(dayOfMonth + " / "+ (monthOfYear+1) + " / " + year);
                }
            },mYear,mMonth,mDay);
            dpd.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePickerDialog picker= new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month,day);
picker.getDatePicker().setTag("id")
```