# How to make a timepicker pop up when edittexts is clicked?

Tags: java, android

Heloo guys
I have been searching the stackoverflow for many days but i haven't found out the solution. Either the question is asked but the contents are out of date which can't be implemented. I want to make a timepicker pop up when edit text is clicked. Please help me in doing this.
Thanking you

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431250/how-to-achieve-multiple-datepicker-functionality-with-two-buttons-and-save-those/30433506#30433506) might help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933330/datepicker-how-to-popup-datepicker-when-click-on-edittext

Answer (score 0):

Simple implementation - use `EditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)` like You would with button since this method is on most `View`'s. Then make it launch timepicker and after hours are selected when finished declare in the primary activity `onActivityResult`and `EditText.setText("whatever You like"). It's that simple.

Comment: Which part of answer is not understandable for You? I won't write whole code for You - I'm supposed only to show You the correct direction.